wifi repeatedly asks for authentication/password
I cannot connect to my university wifi for some reason. Every time I try to connect I get asked to input my password, and then it asks for it again seconds later. I have tried following the commands given in response here:

WiFi keeps asking for authentication, auto authenticate?

WiFi asks for password again and again


I tried running:
Results of sudo dmesg | tail :
output: https://pastebin.com/3RRX80bJ
[58479.180531] wlo1: authenticate with 38:1c:1a:d5:31:3f (local address=4c:d5:77:2f:69:11)
[58479.180543] wlo1: send auth to 38:1c:1a:d5:31:3f (try 1/3)
[58479.181181] wlo1: authenticated
[58479.181376] wlo1: VHT capa missing/short, disabling VHT/HE/EHT
[58479.181453] wlo1: associate with 38:1c:1a:d5:31:3f (try 1/3)
[58479.183879] wlo1: RX AssocResp from 38:1c:1a:d5:31:3f (capab=0x111 status=0 aid=147)
[58479.294754] wlo1: associated
[58479.294809] wlo1: Limiting TX power to 17 dBm as advertised by 38:1c:1a:d5:31:3f
[58481.305188] wlo1: deauthenticating from 38:1c:1a:d5:31:3f by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[58494.835167] wlo1: authenticate with 38:1c:1a:d5:31:3f (local address=4c:d5:77:2f:69:11)
[58494.835175] wlo1: send auth to 38:1c:1a:d5:31:3f (try 1/3)
[58494.835862] wlo1: authenticated
[58494.837016] wlo1: VHT capa missing/short, disabling VHT/HE/EHT
[58494.838030] wlo1: associate with 38:1c:1a:d5:31:3f (try 1/3)
[58494.949957] wlo1: associate with 38:1c:1a:d5:31:3f (try 2/3)
[58495.062009] wlo1: associate with 38:1c:1a:d5:31:3f (try 3/3)
[58495.174065] wlo1: association with 38:1c:1a:d5:31:3f timed out

and
Results of lspci -knn | grep Net -A2 :
:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8852AE 802.11ax PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:8852]
    DeviceName: Realtek Wireless LAN + BT
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:88e1]

Is this a driver problem, or should I run more commands? I'm still a bit new to Ubuntu, so please let me know if I have missed anything.
